# Optional chaining parsing failed in Sonarqube

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

I am using typescript 3.7.5 and getting parse error while running.

Typescript = 3.7.5

INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 amd64
INFO: SonarQube server 8.2.0

ERROR: Failed to parse the file.

Comment: Could you add the offending line and the error message?

Comment: this.establishment.english =  estDetails?.name?.english;

Comment: ERROR: Failed to parse file [path] at line 263: Expression expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be a known issue: https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/1930

The issue is close but I'm still experiencing the same issue.